# How to check if date is valid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My code looks like:

```
if f.thisyear.blank? &&  Date.new(Date.today.year, f.birthday.month, f.birthday.mday ).valid_date?
  f.update_attribute :thisyear, Date.new(Date.today.year, f.birthday.month, f.birthday.mday )
end
```

In the first line, I check for a valid date using:

```
Date.new(Date.today.year, f.birthday.month, f.birthday.mday ).valid_date?
```

This throws an error:

```
`new': invalid date (ArgumentError)
```

How do I have to write my code to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`Date::valid_date?`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-valid_date-3F) is a *class* method, so instead of

```
Date.new(Date.today.year, f.birthday.month, f.birthday.mday).valid_date?
```

use

```
Date.valid_date?(Date.today.year, f.birthday.month, f.birthday.mday)
```